# dotnet core dependency injection to extension method before BuildServiceProvider is called

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core-3.1

I have a dotnet core 3.1 C# XUnit Project.

It has a Startup class containing the following Initialise method:

```
public static IServiceProvider Initialise()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureServices(services);
        return services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
```

The ConfigureServices method contains the following:

```
private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSharedConfiguration(_metadataTokens);
        services.AddLogging();
        services.AddTransient<IStructuredLogger>(x => new StructuredLogger(x.GetRequiredService<ILogger<PortfolioActivation>>()));

        services.AddClientApi(_metadataTokens);
    }
```

The AddClientApi is an extension method containing the following:

```
public static void AddClientApi(this IServiceCollection services, Dictionary<string, string> metadataTokens)
{
services.AddHttpClient(
    LocalSettings.HttpClientTypes.BrewinAvaloqHttpClient, client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(metadataTokens[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.ClientApiBaseAddress]);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(LocalSettings.HttpHeaderKeys.CacheControl, "no-cac
    }
).AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy(builder => builder.WaitAndRetryAsync(new[]
{
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
},
onRetry: (outcome, timespan, retryAttempt, context) =>
{
    //compile error here because I don't have structuredLogger      
    structuredLogger.LogInfo($"Failure on http request: {outcome}. This is retry attempt:[{retryAttempt}]"); 
}
));
}
```

My problem is in the onRety block, I'd like to make use of the "StructuredLogger" service that's been added to the IServiceCollection in the ConfigureServices method. I'm not sure how because at this point, the BuildServiceProvider method has not yet been called?

Comment: Although the accepted answer helped you in your specific case of `AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy`, the title of this question remains unanswered in the general sense :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able extract your service from `IServiceProvider` in the same fashion as you can do it here:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<MyClass>();
services.AddSingleton<MyClass2>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<MyClass>());
```

As stated in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/522), `.AddPolicyHandler()` can be used to get access to `IServiceProvider` by doing:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient("...")
    .AddPolicyHandler((serviceProvider, request) => HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError()
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(new[]
    {
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
    },
    onRetry: (outcome, timespan, retryAttempt, context) =>
    {
        serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IStructuredLogger>()
            .LogInfo($"Failure on http request: {outcome}. This is retry attempt:[{retryAttempt}]");
    }
));
```

Comment: The method "AddClientApi" does not received an IServiceProvider prameter I can make use of. If I add one then I get a compile exception from the line "services.AddClientApi(_metadataTokens);" in the ConfigureServices method because it's not passing the required parameter

Comment: You don't need `IServiceProvider` in `AddClientApi` method, the `serviceProvider` you see in my answer is a `Func` parameter of [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.pollyhttpclientbuilderextensions.addpolicyhandler?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_PollyHttpClientBuilderExtensions_AddPolicyHandler_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IHttpClientBuilder_System_Func_System_IServiceProvider_System_Net_Http_HttpRequestMessage_Polly_IAsyncPolicy_System_Net_Http_HttpResponseMessage___)